# How to get specific data from String using regex in java?

Tags: regex

I have a string.

```
String str= " <decision  CCDBNUM=\"1111111\" adddate=\"20180112\"><decision CCDBNUM=\"2222222\" adddate=\"20180114\"> ";
```

I want to write a regex to fetch a particular value from this string.
My Expected Output is: to fetch only the value of CCDBNUM, i.e,
1111111 2222222

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: try `(?<=CCDBNUM=\\")(.*?)(?=\\")`  https://regex101.com/r/nJIxyc/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
CCDBNUM="([^"]+)"
```

Just get group 1 of each match.

I assume that `CCDBNUM` wouldn't contain the characters `CCDBNUM`. If that's not the case, I suggest you use an XML parser. Regex is not enough for that.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xOHytW/1)

Comment: thanks a lot. this worked:)